# TYPO3 Constants

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Hi in my Constants I have declared a constant

```
PATH_TO = user_vorlagen
```

All ok this is the result:
in Setup:

```
file = Resources/Private/Partials/{$PATH_TO}/landingpage
/LANDINGPAGE_Footer.html
```

This works the path is correctly rendered:

```
file = Resources/Private/Partials/user_vorlagen/landingpage/LANDINGPAGE_Footer.html
```

---

Now my question: i want change this and use a fe_users field `{TSFE:fe_user|user|lockToDomain}`.

This gives me the correct result in debug "user_vorlagen", but if I inserted in path

```
file = Resources/Private/Partials/{TSFE:fe_user|user|lockToDomain}/landingpage...
```

It doesn't work.
I try `file.inserData=1` 
someone can give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

The `.insertData = 1` functionality is only available in TypoScript objects with stdWrap support and I don't think that the file is supporting that.

Either try:

```
file = TEXT
file.value = Resources/Private/Partials/{TSFE:fe_user|user|lockToDomain}/landingpage
file.insertData = 1
```

Or use PHP to insert that variable.

Comment: Just wanted to write the same. +1

Answer (score 0):

It must work in this context.

```
lib.MAIL_WRAP = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.MAIL_WRAP  {
    #stdWrap.editPanel = 1
    #stdWrap.editPanel.allow = move, edit, hide, new
    file = Resources/Private/Partials/{$USER_PATH_MAILINGS}/mail/MAIL_wrap.html
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        10.references {
            table = tt_content
            uid.field = uid
            fieldName = assets
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works:  file.dataWrap= Resources/Private/Partials/{$USER_PATH_MAILINGS}/mail/MAIL_wrap.html